# Is "study abroad program" correct?

Tags: phrase-usage, vocabulary, word-order, hyphens, phrase-structure

Is "study abroad program" correct? For me, in this phrase, "study" is a noun, "abroad" is an adverb, and "program" is a noun, so it doesn't make sense that these three words are ordered in this way without a hyphen between "study" and "abroad". Am I wrong, or is this a phrase that is so widely accepted that correction doesn't matter anymore?

Comment: The syntax is a bit odd, but [it's a widely accepted usage.](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=a+study+abroad+program%2Cstudy+abroad+programs&year_start=1919&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3)

Comment: I think that _study_ is being used as a verb here, not a noun

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"study abroad program" should be considered a compound.  Constructing compounds like this is possible.  Here are some more examples:

> He painted a *go faster stripe* on his car.

> He used the *take-off runway* to land in an emergency.

As with other compounds, they have a meaning that may be more or less clear from the individual parts, and you can't just combine a random verb and adverb to get a new compound that has no currency.

The matter of whether to use a hyphen or not is mostly stylistic.  I'd favour using one as it helps the clarity. But plenty of examples show that it isn't essential.